# Trace request as it propagates through Google Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Say you have an HTTP endpoint which, when triggered, publishes a PubSub message and then sends a response.

There is another Cloud Functions which is subscribed to this event, performs what it needs to perform, and then ends.

How would you go about to trace the entire sequence of function executions triggered by an initial request (in this example, the first HTTP request)?

I see in the Google Cloud Platform logs there is a function Execution ID, but this changes with each function that is triggered hence it's hard to follow the sequence of executions. Is there an automated way of doing this? Or does it need custom implementation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will need a custom solution.  If you want to trace this all the way back to the client request, you will need to generate some unique ID on the client, and pass that along to the HTTP function, which would then pass that along to the pubsub function via the message payload.  And so on.

You might find it helpful to use [StackDriver logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging) to collect the logs around that unique ID.